# Guzzle client request method returns response object instead of request object

Tags: php, guzzle

I am new to Guzzle and tried to read documentation, but still can't find the answer for it.

For example - I get this code from [here](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/request.html#post-requests)

```
$request = $client->post('http://httpbin.org/post', array(), array(
    'custom_field' => 'my custom value',
    'file_field'   => '@/path/to/file.xml'
));

$response = $request->send();
```

I tried to do the same thing, but when $client->post() is executed, it returns a response object, instead of request.
What can be wrong?

I am using the version 6.

Comment: I'd expect a response object to be returned.... it's the response to the request, so that doesn't sound wrong.... why do you think it is?

Comment: I provided code from documentation, so i just dont understand the right vehavior

Comment: That is the right behaviour.... your `$request->send()` sends the request to the `http://httpbin.org/post` server, and gets a response from that server.... that response from the server is the return value that is then being assigned to `$response`

Comment: Yes, in documentation it is right, but i receive response object on $client->post

Comment: Note also that technically it's not a `request` method, it's the `send()` method of the `request` object

Comment: Yes!!! You should get a response object back - [Guzzle docs](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/response.html) - `Sending a request will return a Guzzle\Http\Message\Response object.`

Comment: Calm down, i understand that i must get response obkext, but, i repeat, i cannot invoke send() because i got a response object instead of request

Comment: You mean that `$request` is a response object? The `post()` method executes a `send()`, as does `get()`, etc

Comment: Exactly, that what i wanted to tell

Answer (score 0):

As per [Guzzle Docs](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#sending-requests) all of the "magic methods", `get(), delete(), put(), post(), options(), patch() and head()` will return a response object.

If you check the [GuzzleHttp\Client](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Client.php#L76) source code, you will see that the magic methods are actually abstractions to `Client::request()` handled by `Client::__call()`.

Regardless of the request type, you should always receive a response.

Comment: It just awkward for me, that docs give code, but it does not work exactly as it is.